# select2 automatically select item for ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Is there a way to make select2 control auto select an item when ajax response contain extra data.

I want to implement my controller to in JsonResult mark item as exact  mach and then to select2 control automatic select that without opening drop n down.

From user prespecitve:
If user type in select2 textbox  string that exactly match item on controller. e.g. If user type in barcode and controller method find that bar-code.
Select2 control will immediately select that item without opening dropdown.

If user type in query that is not exactly match controller will return list of items without param exact and select2 will open dropdown to show user possible choice of items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this with AJAX, you need to add a selected option to the select DOM element, and then trigger a change on the select2 widget so it redraws.  Below may be what you are looking for.  This example uses processResults to check to see if there is exactly one match and it matches what the user typed exactly.

```
$("#product_id").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "/api/productLookup",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        term: params.term,
        };
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
        var searchTerm = $("#product_id").data("select2").$dropdown.find("input").val();
        if (data.results.length == 1 && data.results[0].text == searchTerm) {
            $("#product_id").append($("<option />")
                .attr("value", data.results[0].id)
                .html(data.results[0].text)
            ).val(data.results[0].id).trigger("change").select2("close");
        }
        return data;
    },
    minimumInputLength: 8,
    cache: true
  }
});
```

Comment: Will this work inside select2 definition of ajax qery ?

Comment: I would run this as part of the change handler on the #barcode element, so when the barcode got scanned, the product would update.

Comment: I updated my answer to include an example select2 definition that would enable the backend to get the barcode in the ajax request.

Comment: Thnx on trying to help. But I think that you did not understand what I am looking for. An idea is to select2 works on 2 way 1st: When user type part of item contoler will return itenms selec2 two whil open drop'n'down. 2nd: When user type in excatk value of item. Controller will return just one ITEM whit extra data e.g. (selected) and then Select2 will not open dop'n'down it will automacli get selected value. Saving user 2 click

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your question better now...   I updated my answer...   You would probably want to use the minimumInputLength option to suppress the dropdown from showing up early.

Answer (score 1):

```
#this worked for me... using select2 with barcode
var defaultInitialGroup = '';
    $("#idbarang").select2({
        placeholder: "Type/ Scan your barcode item",
        allowClear: true,
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        multiple: true,
        ajax: {
            url: HOST_URL + 'stock/balance/list_xxv',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function(params) {
            return {
            _search_: params.term, // search term
            _page_: params.page,
            _draw_: true,
            _start_: 1,
            _perpage_: 2,
            _paramglobal_: defaultInitialGroup,
            term: params.term,
            };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
            var searchTerm = $("#idbarang").data("select2").$dropdown.find("input").val();
        if (data.items.length === 1 && data.items[0].text === searchTerm) {
        var option = new Option(data.items[0].nmbarang, data.items[0].idbarang, true, true);
        $('#idbarang').append(option).trigger('change').select2("close");
        // manually trigger the `select2:select` event
         $('#idbarang').trigger({
         type: 'select2:select',
         params: {
            data: data
        }
        });}
        params.page = params.page || 1;
        return {
        results: data.items,
            pagination: {
            more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
            }
            };
            },
            cache: false
        },
        escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
        return markup;
        }, // let our custom formatter work
        templateResult: formatItem, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
        templateSelection: formatItemSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    })
function formatItem(repo) {
if (repo.loading) return repo.text;
var markup ="<div class='select2-result-repository__description'>" + repo.idbarang +"<i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i>"+ repo.nmbarang +"</div>";
return markup;
}
function formatItemSelection(repo){
return repo.nmbarang || repo.text;
}
```